# How to concatenate variables in another one in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I've set some variables in my "Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables", and I want to use them to define my Terraform state file name:

Variables:

- PROJECT_NAME ('myproject')
- ENVIRONMENT ('dev')

In my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/
  TF_STATE_NAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}_${ENVIRONMENT}
```

The problem is that when my state file is created during the pipeline execution, the variables values are not replaced in the file name, and it looks like this:

```
mygroup_${PROJECT_NAME}_${ENVIRONMENT}
```

Instead of what I expected:

```
mygroup_myproject_dev
```

The idea here is to **have a different state file for each environment**.

Comment: what Gitlab version are you using ? What you are trying to do is only possible since [Gitlab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#use-variables-in-other-variables)

Comment: If your version is correct regarding @NicolasPepinster's comment, try quotes around your variable value's, ie `TF_ROOT: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/"` and `TF_STATE_NAME: "${PROJECT_NAME}_${ENVIRONMENT}"`

Comment: Damn it! The version is 13.12.2! And unfortunately, I have no control on this Gitlab instance...I'll try to contact the administrators. Thanks for your help!